# Even after autoplay="false" preload="none", Video is starting without clicking on play button

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api, dropbox, dropbox-api

In following Code, autoplay="false" preload="none" set but still Video is auto playing.

Where is the problem?

What I am missing?

```
new_video = document.createElement('video');
new_video.setAttribute('controls','true');
//new_video.setAttribute('autoBuffering','true');
new_video.setAttribute('preload','none');//autoPlay: false, 'preload':'auto'
new_video.setAttribute('autoPlay','false');
//new_video.setAttribute('type','video/mp4;codecs=&quot;vp8, vorbis&quot;');
video = document.getElementById('RIZfC358yRk').appendChild(new_video);
source = document.createElement('source');  
source.setAttribute('src','https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/87532981/Ella%20May%20and%20the%20Wishing%20Stone%20By%20Cary%20Fagan.mp4');
video.appendChild(source);
video.load();
video.play();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use "autostart" attribute instead of "autoPlay":

```
new_video.setAttribute('autostart','false');
```

And remove the last line,

```
video.play();
```

Comment: after removing last line, it is not starting automatically. Thanks.